# Update Database from Entity Model without losing content

Tags: database, ado.net-entity-data-model

My question's title should tell you what I am asking about.

Is there any way to update my database from an entity model without losing the inserted content?

I can't be bothered copying all this stuff every time I make a change.

Comment: update database from Entity Model to a different model? or just make changes in your database???

Comment: I have the same problem. Specially in the early stages when your model isn't definite but you already have some semi static content in your DB. It's nice you can have entity framework create your DB but it's really annoying if you have to add or import data all the time.

Comment: Yes, I have an add-in for EFv4/VS2010 ( http://www.huagati.com/edmxtools/ ) that can generate incremental SQL-DDL change scripts for EFv4 models in VS2010, as shown in the intro screencast at http://bit.ly/cTbreP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack"?

[Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87)